# Is there a way to plot an array directly (and only) on top of another array using matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D 5x5 array that contains 10 nan values (the remaining 15 are zeros), I want to plot a second 2D 5x5 array that contains 15 nan values (the remaining 10 are zeros) so that the 10 zeros of the second array are placed where the nan values of the first array are and that the 15 zeros of the first array are placed where the nan values of the second array are, how do I do it using numpy and matplotlib?

I have randomly generated the two arrays and applied a Boolean mask (np.isnan), but I'm unclear on what to do next. I have tried googling it but found no answer whatsoever. I have tried applying the Boolean mask to arr2 or adding it to arr2, but the closest I got to a result was having both arrays only filling 15 cells in total out of the 25 available.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

arr1 = np.zeros((5, 5))
no_arr1 = 10
for i in range(no_arr1):
    x = np.random.randint(0, 5)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 5)
    arr1[x, y] = np.nan
col1 = ["lime"]
one = mcolors.ListedColormap(col1)
mask_1 = np.isnan(arr1)
mask_1_2 = arr1 == 0

arr2 = np.zeros((5, 5))
no_arr2 = 15
for i in range(no_arr2):
    x = np.random.randint(0, 5)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 5)
    arr2[x, y] = np.nan
col2 = ["hotpink"]
two = mcolors.ListedColormap(col2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(arr1, cmap=one)
ax.imshow(arr2, cmap=two)

plt.show()
```

You can ignore the colors part, I only did it so I would be able to see clearly what was being plotted on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new array which has zeros where the original has nan values, and nan where the original has non-nan values, you can use this:

```
arr2 = np.where(np.isnan(arr1), 0, np.nan)
```